# Dealing with certain type of Inflection point

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, graphing-functions

here a function and its derivatives accordingly by: 
$$f(x)=x-6x^{1/3}$$
$$f'(x)=1-2x^{-2/3}$$
$$f''(x)=\frac{4}{3}x^{-5/3}$$

as we can't get zero for $f''(x)$ and when i try to make derivative not exist on $f''(x)$ it would also make $f'(x)$ not exist at same time. Which should leave us no other choice than observe the concavity directly from the original function , but exactly how to solve this?

Comment: Well, you can conclude that $f''>0$ always.

Comment: @MattiP. That's not true. We have $f''\lt0$ for $x\lt0$.

Comment: But is the function even defined for $x<0$? $x^{1/3}$ doesn't behave nicely, unless we interpret it to mean $\sqrt[3]{x}$.

Comment: @MattiP. The OP tagged `real-analysis` so I assume they mean the real-valued cube root - $x^{1/3}=\text{sgn}(x)\sqrt[3]{|x|}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An inflection point occurs when the value of $f''(x)$ changes sign and the curve $f(x)$ is continuous. In our case $f''(x)\gt0$ for all $x\gt0$ and $f''(x)\lt0$ for all $x\lt0$. Although $f''(0)$ is undefined, the value of $f''(x)$ changes sign at the point where $x=0$ and $f(x)$ is continuous at this point hence $(0,0)$ is the only inflection point of $f(x)$.

Comment: this is very insightful, and it clear enough if if we put some $x>0$ we will get positive number on second derivative and if $x<0$ we will get negative number,but when i'm studied this first time we need one of two conditions that need to be fulfilled , so does it mean when encounter problems like this , we allowed to ignore both?

Comment: We don't need $f''(x)=0$ we just need a sign change to occur in $f''(x)$. But if we have $f''(a)=0$ and $f'''(a)\ne0$ then the point $(a,f(a))$ is an inflection point as a sign change must occur (assuming $f(x)$ is continuous). So the usual method to find inflection points is to let $f''(x)=0$ as you have stated.